# Use SUBSTR() with MySQL WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to use a query like this:

```
SELECT `id`, `userid` FROM `table` WHERE SUBSTR(`displayname`, 0, 5)='aString'
```

So I want to `SUBSTR()` the `WHERE` part, not the column part, but it seems not to work...

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work? An error message or indicative output would be necessary for a good question.

Comment: Because (see my own answer) I made the mistake, that MySQL starts a string on 1, PHP starts on 0. So I didn't get an output but also no error message.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use it:

```
SELECT `id`, `userid` 
FROM `table` 
WHERE SUBSTR(`displayname`, 1, 7)='aString';
```

It will work.

Keep in mind that this condition is not `SARGable` and won't use index on `displayname` if exists any.

---

You could rewrite it as:

```
SELECT `id`, `userid` 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `displayname` LIKE 'aString%';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working as following (please note the `1` instead of `0`):

```
SELECT `id`, `userid` FROM `table` WHERE SUBSTR(`displayname`, 1, 5)='aString'
```